# My wordpress websites on VPS server is getting hacked regularly

Tags: wordpress, security, server, vps

I have purchased VPS server from OVH. I have installed Vestacp, it has been more than 6 months and I'm still facing issues with server security. Sometimes my Wordpress websites get hacked, sometimes the server is slow or not responding for a whole day. I'm not able to identify issue. Someone please. help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic checklist to get you started:

1. Download and run WPScan against your site you can obtain this [here](http://wpscan.org/).
2. Change all your passwords, Since it's a virtual private server your pem file might of been compromised. So change your password for all access to the site.
3. Update all your plugins, I can't stress enough and I see businesses do this all the time, they don't update their plugins. Make sure you are updated to the latest wordpress version as well.
4. If you website is beyond repair at this time download all the files and then do a fresh install of Wordpress and restore what you can.
5. Invest in a SSL Certificate to encrypt your data, this will protect you and your users from MITM (man in the middle) attacks.
6. Update your .htaccess file with restrictions try [these](http://www.minitek.gr/blog/the-9-most-important-security-settings-in-htaccess).
7. If you don't have an IDS/IPS to detect SQL injection consider installing ModSecurity, you can download that [here](https://www.modsecurity.org/).
8. Since it's a virtual private server if a backdoor has been planted you might want to consider as well doing a full wipe and restore of files you know are secure.
9. Close ports you don't need. If you don't use certain ports all the time close them.
10. Update the webserver applications, apache, mysql, and others. If you don't have the latest version you should be able to download them manually and if it's Linux just compile and run the latest source.
11. For all the countries that don't mean anything to your business block all of them with a country blocking plugin but make sure it's secure, the key is to do your research.
12. Install something like WPSecurity and limit the amount of failed logins before being locked out or having the ip address blocked for certain usernames after so many failed attempts.

If it's a Linux VPS try these commands to see what your server is up to:

```
#Check for remote connections
netstat -a
#Allows to monitor network usage by application
nethogs eth0
#Allows to monitor the system log for authorizations
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
#Allows to monitor firewall log
tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
#Allows to monitor packets (look for malformed ones)
tshark -i eth0
```

You should be doing **incident response** at this time more than anything since it's a VPS server. There are some great methodologies on [this website](https://cert.societegenerale.com/en/publications.html) that may help as well.

Hope this helps.

--lillypad

Comment: Thanks lillypad, I had already added ninjawirewall wp edition plugin. and for server i had installed maldet and Brute Force Detection. But, its not enough. Many people are facing same problem with WordPress. But, still there is no better solution for this problem.

Comment: Since it's a VPS Server have you checked to see if it's a backdoor? Reason being if they are on the server itself and not just using the Wordpress login all of those things are not going to help you at all. In my opinion you should be doing incident response at this time not just installing extra security.

Comment: Maldet like any other AV tool is only going to find things with specific signatures (MD5) and Hex patterns. Custom made and encrypted reverse shells are not going to be picked up by this. Should be not looking for the file causing the issue as much as you should be checking how they are getting connected. That's all part of incident response though